# How to compare an image folder with a csv file in php?

Tags: php, csv

I have a folder of images that are named like this:

[image]

I have a csv file with this information and it is the two columns 'Product Style' and 'Product Color ID' that I am interested in:

```
Season Code ID;Product Business Area DESC;Product Business Area ID;Product Group DESC;Product Group ID;Product Item Group DESC;Product Item Group ID;Product Gender;Product Activity;Product Style Code;Product Style Name;Product Colour DESC;Product Colour ID;Product Size ID;Sample size;All Sizes;Product Sku ID;Product Barcode ID;Country Of Origin;Construction;Weight;Supply Chain Code ID;Fob Unit Price;Fob Currency;Landed Unit Price;Landed Currency ;Wholesale UnitPrice;Wholesale Currency ;Factory Code;Season Type
FY22S1;Apparel;;Wovens;460;Shorts;4602;Unisex;City Life;13363;Praca Hiking Short v2 Wmn;Black;902;10;10;6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18;13363/902/10;9,42E+12;Made in Vietnam;"  Main: Nylon / Elastane 95/5 (%) ;  : Exclusive of Decoration  (%) ";175 g ;;;NZD;;;;;SPLR_1117;Summer
FY22S1;Apparel;;Wovens;460;Shorts;4602;Unisex;City Life;13363;Praca Hiking Short v2 Wmn;Black;902;12;10;6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18;13363/902/12;9,42E+12;Made in Vietnam;"  Main: Nylon / Elastane 95/5 (%) ;  : Exclusive of Decoration  (%) ";175 g ;;;NZD;;;;;SPLR_1117;Summer
FY22S1;Apparel;;Wovens;460;Shorts;4602;Unisex;City Life;13363;Praca Hiking Short v2 Wmn;Black;902;14;10;6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18;13363/902/14;9,42E+12;Made in Vietnam;"  Main: Nylon / Elastane 95/5 (%) ;  : Exclusive of Decoration  (%) ";175 g ;;;NZD;;;;;SPLR_1117;Summer
FY22S1;Apparel;;Wovens;460;Shorts;4602;Unisex;City Life;13363;Praca Hiking Short v2 Wmn;Black;902;16;10;6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18;13363/902/16;9,42E+12;Made in Vietnam;"  Main: Nylon / Elastane 95/5 (%) ;  : Exclusive of Decoration  (%) ";175 g ;;;NZD;;;;;SPLR_1117;Summer
FY22S1;Apparel;;Wovens;460;Shorts;4602;Unisex;City Life;13363;Praca Hiking Short v2 Wmn;Black;902;18;10;6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18;13363/902/18;9,42E+12;Made in Vietnam;"  Main: Nylon / Elastane 95/5 (%) ;  : Exclusive of Decoration  (%) ";175 g ;;;NZD;;;;;SPLR_1117;Summer
FY22S1;Apparel;;Wovens;460;Shorts;4602;Unisex;City Life;13363;Praca Hiking Short v2 Wmn;Black;902;6;10;6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18;13363/902/6;9,42E+12;Made in Vietnam;"  Main: Nylon / Elastane 95/5 (%) ;  : Exclusive of Decoration  (%) ";175 g ;;;NZD;;;;;SPLR_1117;Summer
```

I wrote a php script that allows me to compare the name of the images with the one in the csv file to know which photo is missing in the folder :

```
13363_902;"Missing image"
13363_902;"Missing image"
13363_902;"Missing image"
13363_902;"Missing image"
13363_902;"Missing image"
13363_902;"Missing image"
13363_902;"Missing image"
13363_913;"Missing image"
13363_913;"Missing image"
13363_913;"Missing image"
13363_913;"Missing image"
13363_913;"Missing image"
13363_913;"Missing image"
```

The problem is that the script is very long for large folders of images and I noticed that some images in the folder were counted as missing when they are in the folder.

Where can this error and speed problem come from please?

```
<?php

// ini_set('max_execution_time', 61200);
$path = 'C:/wamp64/www/KMD/verif/SS22 International Range (2000x2000 jpeg)/';

   $dir  = $path;
   $allFiles = scandir($dir);

   foreach($allFiles as $file) 
   {
        if (!in_array($file,array(".","..")))
      { 

          $file = $dir.$file;
          $filename = basename( $file );

          //We delete Online version-
          $explode = explode("-", $filename);
          // echo $explode[1]; //14109_NOR_Tauro_Hooded_Jacket_Men_a.jpg

          $explode2 = explode("_", $explode[1]);
          $name_picture = $explode2[0].'_'.$explode2[1]; 
          // echo $name_picture;

          if (($handle = fopen("KMD.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
            fgets($handle); // skip header line
        
                // Create CSV output file
                $chemin = 'csv/photos.csv'; 
                $delimiteur = ';';
        
                $fichier_csv = fopen($chemin, 'w+');
                fprintf($fichier_csv, chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF));
        
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0000000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
                 if ($data[0] != null) {
                    
                    $name_file = $data[9].'_'.$data[12];
                    // echo $name_file;
                    // echo '<br>';
                    // echo $name_picture;
                    // echo '<br>';

                    if ($name_file != $name_picture)
                    {
                        $resultat = [$name_file,'Missing image'];
                        print_r($name_file.': Missing image');
                        echo "<br>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $resultat = [$name_file,'Image in folder'];
                        print_r($name_file.': Image in folder');
                        echo "<br>";
                        
                    }
               }
        
               fputcsv($fichier_csv, $resultat, $delimiteur);
            }
          
            fclose($fichier_csv);//close
        
        }                    
     }
  }

?>

<!-- Link file -->
Result file :
<a href='csv/photos.csv' target='_blank'>Dowload</a>
```

Comment: how does the depiction of the csv ( why not add a real sample from the csv? )relate to the picture of the images ( what is the full filename - I see no file extension in the image )

Comment: I just updated my question to make it clearer @ProfessorAbronsius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for better performance, you should avoid to open/write/close in a file in foreach loop.

```
// Create CSV output file
$chemin = 'csv/photos.csv'; 
$delimiteur = ';';
$fichier_csv = fopen($chemin, 'w+');
fprintf($fichier_csv, chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF));

foreach($allFiles as $file) 
{
    // do stuff then, write
    fputcsv($fichier_csv, $resultat, $delimiteur);
}

fclose($fichier_csv);
```

Then, in your loop you are comparing the current file to the whole list and add the `resultat` each time. That's why you don't have to expected results.

You could prepare a simple array of file.

```
$kmd = [];
if (($handle = fopen("KMD.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";"); // skip header line
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        if ($data[0] != null) {
            $kmd[] = $data[9].'_'.$data[12];
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Then, in the loop :

```
foreach($allFiles as $file) 
{
    // ...

    if (! in_array($name_picture, $kmd))
    {
        $resultat = [$name_picture,'Missing image'];
        print_r($name_file.': Missing image');
        echo "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        $resultat = [$name_picture,'Image in folder'];
        print_r($name_file.': Image in folder');
        echo "<br>";
        
    }

    fputcsv($fichier_csv, $resultat, $delimiteur);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanations, but I don't understand in which order should I put your 3 pieces of code?

Comment: [here](https://3v4l.org/kJ91t) is an overview of the full code (untested).

Comment: I just tested it but it does the opposite of what I wanted. In fact I wanted the list of `$data[9]_$data[12]` of the csv file and in front if the image is in the folder or not, here I have the list of the names of the images instead of the csv file

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really understand your comment. You need to check if the current file (`$name_picture`) is in the KMD's CSV? (did you check [this version](https://3v4l.org/kJ91t)).

Comment: At the end I want in my final csv file the list of `$name_file` and opposite if in the image folder there is this image or not.
For example in my `KMD.csv` file if the file starts with 
`13363_902;
13363_902;
13363_912;
13363_916;`
I want to know if there are the pictures or not. Is it clearer for you?

Comment: With your new version it does the same. I have the list of all the photos in the final csv file. I want to copy and paste the two columns of the first csv file and check opposite in the image folder if this name is there or not. Do you want me to send you a complete example?

Comment: Ok, send me a complete example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230359/discussion-between-mathieu27-and-syscall).